# How to add something after a function

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

Is there any possible way that I can run some code to be outputted right after a specific function in a template file?

For example, I want to add an author bio in the single-post.php template bur after a function is called ( `do_something()` ).

Is that possible?

From what I can understand, you can only add things to the content and before the content.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How is the function called, does it output anything? You can use `do_action('my_hook')` hooks

Comment: This is where filters and actions exist. Also, this where you can use and modify a theme by creating a child theme.

Comment: @bravokeyl yes, the `do_something()` function outputs some content (meta info of the post) and I want to run my function right after this function's content.

Comment: @Drupalizeme I'm building a plugin, can you give me an example please?

Comment: Is '`do_something()`' a function you wrote? Or a function that's in a theme? Or a Core WordPress function? The straight answer to the question you asked is: "depends on the function". So you need to be more specific to get an actual answer.

Comment: @mrKC.988 Can you tell me what you want exatly and how you will display post meta?

Comment: @JacobPeattie @Patrik, The function is added by a theme and it's called `pk_theme_post_meta()` it just checks if the page is post and echo out the meta tag of the post below the title (date, author name, comments, categories). I need my code to be added right after this function call. Thanks.

Comment: It’ll only be possible if the theme supports it. You’d need to contact the theme author to find out. And even if it did it’s only going to work for that theme. So if this is a public plugin you’ll need a different approach.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you I will ask the theme developers, my plugin work with just one theme otherwise I wouldn't take this approach. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

You can put this example into your functions.php file :

```
function insertContent($content) {

   $content.= "<div>";
   $content.="additional content";
   $content.= "</div>";

   return $content;
}
// put this line in your custom function or in your template file (single)
add_filter ('the_content', 'insertContent');
```

Bye !

Comment: This will output my content after `the_content`, what I need is add my content inside `the_content` and after a specific function runs. Thank you.